# How to change the Size of the Sitecore Standard holders cache

Tags: sitecore

When using the Sitecore Cache Admin tool (.../sitecore/admin/cache.aspx) to view the caches I have Standard holders listed. What is the purpose of that particular cache and more important, how do I change the size of that cache.

The Sitecore version is 5.3.2 (rev. 090317).

[image: Screen dump of the cache listing]

Comment: Are you sure it is not a customization of the default cache.aspx? Can you screenshot it and add to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have added a link to a screen dump of the cache listing.

Comment: The caches are picked by CacheManager class from web.config (I mean standard Sitecore caches). I strongly recommend you to check your custom code for potential injects of a custom cache class. As far as I remember, the method to register new caches is internal, so it could be a dirty reflection hack on your side ;-)

Comment: I've checked for "Standards Holders" on some sites. It seems it's not in Sitecore 6 solutions but only Sitecore 5.3 solutions.

Dunno if that helps, but it might narrow it down.

And maybe this is a question for Sitecore: http://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from Sitecore Support:

The cache is used by Log, Theme and Language providers.

To change the cache size value just add the following setting to the web.config file:

```
<setting name="Caching.SmallCacheSize" value="200KB"/>
```

Comment: Brilliant! It's good news that I was wrong with my assumption about your custom code ;-)

Comment: Just to clear this up for people like me (who could be confused in thinking it's a web application setting): it's actually a "<sitecore><settings>" setting, so add it somewhere to a custom Sitecore config.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you are asking for, but there are ways to adjust the cache sizes, you can find them here:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Sitecore%20Performance/Caching/Cache%20Sizing.aspx

if this isn't what you were looking for, please do say so.

Comment: Thank you, but I need information about how to change the "Standard holders" cache specific as it is not listed in web.config where most others caches sizes are specified.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked in Sitecore 5.3, but I don't recall there ever being a 'Standard holders' cache. You may need to check your code for use of a custom cache named 'Standard Holders'.

Comment: I stand corrected! There is a 'Standard holders' cache in Sitecore 5.3.